# How may I deploy a Wt application with the built-in web server?

Tags: c++, frameworks, wt

I am new using Wt and I would like to know what I must do to get an example (let’s say Hello) working on a web server (Apache or free webhost for testing).

I know how to use the built-in web server ; I have to launch that command :

```
./hello.wt --docroot . --http-address 0.0.0.0 --http-port 8080
```

Then, I go to http://127.0.0.1:8080/ and it is working.

But, how may I do this using Apache ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added FastCgiServer /dir/to/Wt/Examples/Hello/hello.wt to my fastcgi.conf and now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `-DCONNECTOR_FCGI=ON` to cmake and follow these instructions for [configuring FastCGI with Apache](http://redmine.webtoolkit.eu/projects/wt/wiki/Fastcgi_on_apache)

Comment: Hello, I am not using cmake. I compiled my application with g++ like that : g++ hello.C -lwt -lwtfcgi -o hello.wt I edited my fastcgi.conf the same way as the wiki and I add a .htaccess with Options +ExecCGI in my server root. Did I make something wrong ? I got a 500 Internal Server Error…

Comment: Make sure that the dir specified for FastCgiIpcDir exists (you may have to create it yourself) and see if you have errors in your Apache error log.

Comment: Hello, the directory exists. But I have some text in the error.log. Two are fatal : [2010-Nov-03 22:38:05.024571] 3180 - [fatal] "Cannot create run directory '/var/run/wt'" ——— But this dir exists, strange ? The other fatal one is : [2010-Nov-03 22:38:05.063209] 3182 - [fatal] "bind(): Permission denied" ——— There are a lot of other errors, but there are notice or warn… Thanks for your help.

Comment: It may be a permission issue. Try chowning it to the apache user.

Comment: Hello, now I have these errors in error.log : [2010-Nov-03 
[2010-Nov-03 23:11:26.315726] 3884 - [notice] "Reading Wt config file: /etc/wt/wt_config.xml (location = '/dir/to/Wt/Examples/hello/hello.wt')"
[2010-Nov-03 23:11:26.316267] 3884 - [fatal] "bind(): Permission denied"
[Wed Nov 03 23:11:27 2010] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/dir/to/Wt/Examples/hello/hello.wt" has failed to remain running for 30 seconds given 3 attempts, its restart interval has been backed off to 600 seconds

Comment: Verify the permissions of the socket path set in `SocketPath`

Comment: Hello, I just added FastCgiServer /dir/to/Wt/Examples/Hello/hello.wt to my fastcgi.conf ——————— and now it's working. I tought I tried it. Thanks for your help.